# Error 400 and 200 with useEffect React Hook

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, react-hooks, use-effect

I have an API, with Node and MongoDB.

I do the following component with this request :

```
export default function Balance() {
    const uid = useContext(UidContext)

    useEffect(() => {
        axios({
            method: "get",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/balance/${uid}`
        }).then(response => console.log(response.data[0]));
    }, [uid]);

    return (
        <section>
            Walet
        </section>
    )
}
```

And I get an error, AND the results I want :
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUZeE.png)

I don't understand why I get an error, and then the code 200 ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `uid` is null at first. You can do a *null* check:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      if(uid !== null){
        axios({
            method: "get",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/balance/${uid}`
        }).then(response => console.log(response.data[0]));
       }
    }, [uid]);
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that ?! Thank you !